# second file_get_contents in simple_html_dom not working

Tags: php

What is the problem with this code?
Error:This page isnt working.
it works without $post_str=file_get_contents($post_url->href);
i test $post_url->href out of foreach with echo and it show url.it is not working only in file_get_contents
please help me.

```
require_once("inc/simple_html_dom.php");
    for($page_number=1;$page_number<=1;$page_number++) {
        $page_url="https://songsara.net/page/{$page_number}";
        $page_str=file_get_contents($page_url);
        $page_base=new simple_html_dom();
        $page_base->load($page_str);
        foreach($page_base->find('.postbox-i') as $post) {
            foreach($post->find('.post-img-hover a') as $post_url) {
                echo "url: ".$post_url->href."</br>";
            }
            $post_str=file_get_contents($post_url->href);
            $post_base=new simple_html_dom();
            $post_base->load($post_str);
            $track_index=1;
            foreach($post_base->find('.audioplayer-tracklist .audioplayer-track-item .audioplayer-item-dl a') as $track_url) {
                echo "->trackurl_{$track_index}: ".$track_url->href."</br>";
                $track_index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what does `$post_url->href` look like exactly? If it is a relative url, you would need to prepend the the domain. Also note that you only work with the last link that you find, the results of other links are echoed out in the loop, but never used.

Comment: looks like `file_get_contents` is throwing a Warning. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-errors): "An E_WARNING level error is generated if filename cannot be found, maxlength is less than zero, or if seeking to the specified offset in the stream fails."

Comment: this is one of url: https://songsara.net/34698/turkey-instrumental-vol-9.html it exists.

Comment: You should add the **exact** output of `$post_url->href` to your post.

Comment: If you want extract html tags and get specific tag name with it's atribute(value) You need to use simple_html_dom library(http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

because file_get_content() function is not for extracting html tags but this is used to rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Likeky `$post_url->href` is a relative url, just prepend domain

Comment: i test $post_url->href out of foreach with echo and it show url.it is not working only in file_get_contents

Comment: What error arised?
I watched page https://songsara.net/page/1, it contains 18 items `.post-img-hover a`, which means that your code executes 18 requests. may be it falls by timeout?

Answer (score 0):

try this one ...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$base = 'your_url_here';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Create a DOM object
$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html_base->load($str);

//get all category links
foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element->href );
    echo "</pre>";
}

$html_base->clear(); 
unset($html_base);
```

Comment: i tested that.it has same problem.

Comment: did you download simple_html_dom library and did you include correctly???

Comment: i tested that too.it is not working after send multi request.